# Find and set Hadoop logs to verbose level

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I need to track what is happening when I run a job or upload a file to HDFS. I do this using `sql profiler` in sql server. However, I miss such a tool for hadoop and so I am assuming that I can get some information from `logs`. I thing all logs are stored at /var/logs/hadoop/ but I am confused with what file I need to look at and how to set that file to capture detailed level information.

I am using HDP2.2.

Thanks,
Sree

Answer (score 0):

'Hadoop' represents an entire ecosystem of different products. Each one has its own logging.

- HDFS consists of NameNode and DataNode services. Each has its own log. Location of logs is distribution dependent. See [File Locations](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0-Win/bk_HDP_Install_Win/content/ref-8896fe3b-8788-4a88-b7cc-d77d6f2481fc.1.html) for Hortonworks or [Apache Hadoop Log Files: Where to find them in CDH, and what info they contain](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/09/apache-hadoop-log-files-where-to-find-them-in-cdh-and-what-info-they-contain/) for Cloudera.
- In Hadoop 2.2, MapReduce ('jobs') is a specific application in YARN, so you are talking about ResourceManager and NodeManager services (the YARN components), each with its own log, and then there is the MRApplication (the M/R component), which is a YARN applicaiton yet with its own log.
- Jobs consists of taks, and tasks themselves have their own logs.
- In Hadoop 2 there is a dedicated Job History service tasked with collecting and storing the logs from the jobs executed.
- Higher level components (eg. Hive, Pig, Kafka) have their own logs, asside from the logs resulted from the jobs they submit (which are logging as any job does).

The good news is that vendor specific distribution (Cloudera, Hortonworks etc) will provide some specific UI to expose the most common logs for ease access. Usually they expose the JobHistory service collected logs from the UI that shows job status and job history.

I cannot point you to anything SQL Profiler equivalent, because the problem space is orders of magnitude more complex, with many different products, versions and vendor specific distributions being involved. I recommend to start by reading about and learning how the [Job History server](http://hortonworks.com/blog/elephants-can-remember-mapreduce-job-history-in-hdp-2-0/) runs and how it can be accessed.